# JQuery date picker control always shows required though it is not

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC4 (Razor view)/JQuery application in which I have a jQuery datepicker control hooked up to a ***Date of Birth*** Property of a Model with type DateTime, as mentioned below:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.DOB, new { @class = "dp", id = "dp1",value="" })
```

Jquery code:

```
$(function() {
        $("#dp1").datepicker({
            yearRange: "-70:+0", 
            duration: '',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear:true,
            showTime: false,
            constrainInput: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
         });
    });
```

Model:

```
   [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]       
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

As shown in the Model definition, I have not decorated the DOB property with Required attribute. The issue is, when I hit the Submit button, the validator always complains that `DOB is required`, which is not. I was able to bypass this issue by using Html.TextBox instead of TextBoxFor. But, I need to use TextBoxFor in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DateTime** is value type, same as, for example, integer. So by default in validation model of MVC it will be marked as required. You have two options. First option: put this in your Application_Start() of Global.asax file:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

Second option, you can declare it using nullable type:

```
[Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]       
public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
```

First option will deal with client-side validation, but for server side it will say, that model state has errors. Second option will work both for client and server.